# Exclude items of one list in another with different object data types, LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, list

I have two lists filled with their own data.
lets say there are two models `Human` and `AnotherHuman`. Each model contains different fields, however they have some common fields like `LastName, FirstName, Birthday, PersonalID`.

```
List<Human> humans = _unitOfWork.GetHumans();
List<AnotherHuman> anotherHumans = _unitofWork.GetAnotherHumans();
```

I would like to exclude the items from list `anotherHumans` where `LastName, FirstName, Birthday` are all equal to the corresponding fields of any item in list `humans`.

However if any item in `anotherHumans` list has `PersonalID` and item in list `humans` have the same `PersonalID`, then it is enough to compare `Human` with `AnotherHuman` only by this `PersonalID`, otherwise by `LastName, FirstName and Birthday`.

I tried to create new list of dublicates and exclude it from `anotherHumans`:

```
List<AnotherHuman> duplicates = new List<AnotherHuman>();
foreach(Human human in humans)
{
   AnotherHuman newAnotherHuman = new AnotherHuman();
   newAnotherHuman.LastName = human.LastName;
   newAnotherHuman.Name= human.Name;
   newAnotherHuman.Birthday= human.Birthday;
   duplicates.Add(human) 
}
anotherHumans = anotherHumans.Except(duplicates).ToList();
```

But how can I compare `PersonalID` from both lists if it presents (it is nullable). Is there any way to get rid from creating new instance of AnotherHuman and list of duplicates and use LINQ only?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of creating new objects, how about checking the properties as part of the linq query

```
List<Human> humans = _unitOfWork.GetHumans();
List<AnotherHuman> anotherHumans = _unitofWork.GetAnotherHumans();

// Get all anotherHumans where the record does not exist in humans
var result = anotherHumans
               .Where(ah => !humans.Any(h => h.LastName == ah.LastName
                               && h.Name == ah.Name
                               && h.Birthday == ah.Birthday
                               && (!h.PersonalId.HasValue || h.PersonalId == ah.PersonalId)))
               .ToList();
```

Comment: For every item in anotherHumans, you'd need to iterate the humans collection, so performance of this would degrade significantly as the sizes of the collections increase.

Comment: This will only compare items that have a `PersonalID`. I don't think that this is what was asked.

Comment: Still not so good, because in the case that a `PersonalID` is present, there's no requirement to check the LastName, Name and Age, right?

Comment: I've updated the `PersonalID` fix.  With regard to performance, I agree that this will degrade with large datasets however I am not sure this is a concern of the op

Comment: `LastName`, `Name`, and `Birthday` are always checked.  The final line will return true if the `PersonalId` is null or the `PersonalId` matches that of another human

Comment: How do you use lambda expression in Contains()?? It must accept an object,isn't it? Contains(human)?

Comment: Sorry my fault. should be `.Any`. Updating

Comment: Any() returns a bool value, you cannot convert it ToList()

Comment: I was missing a bracket at the end (before the `.ToList()`).  you probably are to

Answer (score 19):

```
var duplicates = from h in humans
                 from a in anotherHumans
                 where (h.PersonalID == a.PersonalID) ||
                       (h.LastName == a.LastName && 
                        h.FirstName == a.FirstName && 
                        h.Birthday == a.Birthday)
                 select a;

anotherHumans = anotherHumans.Except(duplicates);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var nonIdItems = anotherHumans
   .Where(ah => !ah.PersonalID.HasValue)
   .Join(humans, 
         ah => new{ah.LastName, 
           ah.FirstName, 
           ah.Birthday}, 
         h => new{h.LastName, 
           h.FirstName, 
           h.Birthday}, 
         (ah,h) => ah);
var idItems = anotherHumans
   .Where(ah => ah.PersonalID.HasValue)
   .Join(humans, 
         ah => ah.PersonalID
         h => h.PersonalID, 
         (ah,h) => ah);
var allAnotherHumansWithMatchingHumans = nonIdItems.Concat(idItems);
var allAnotherHumansWithoutMatchingHumans = 
      anotherHumans.Except(allAnotherHumansWithMatchingHumans);
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this extension method:
Notice that the second sequence can have a different type, however you have to specify the keys in each one and optionally the comparer.

```
  public static IEnumerable<TOuter> Except<TOuter, TInner, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer, IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
        Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector, Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) {
     IEnumerable<TOuter> iguales = outer.Join(
        inner           : inner,
        outerKeySelector: tOuter => outerKeySelector(tOuter),
        innerKeySelector: tInner => innerKeySelector(tInner),
        resultSelector  : (o, _) => o,
        comparer        : comparer);
     return outer.Except(iguales);
  }
```

Here's how you can use it

```
     String name = "John";
     Char[] chars = { 'h', 'n' };
     var result = name.Except(
        inner           : chars,
        outerKeySelector: c => c,
        innerKeySelector: c => c); // result will contain J, o
```