# Delete from List<T> where row exists in List<string>

Tags: c#, list

I have a List(Person) that contains all person records and a List(string) that contains 10 forenames. 
I want a new List(Person) that only has the records that match on the forename in List(String) (assume all forenames are unique)

How do I do this using LINQ?

Comment: Hi, please show sample input and expected output, as well as code you might have tried so far.

Comment: How do you do it *without* LINQ? Don´t overcomplicate things. Just write some naive implementation and *afterards* ask how you may simplify that. What did you try yourself and where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: find idea on how to do that here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19539822/559144

Comment: I have tried all sorts but my understanding of LINQ isn't good enough. I have tried things such as List<Person> NewList = AllPeople.Select(x => x.Code).Intersect(ForenameList).ToList(); and List<Person> NewList = AllPeople.RemoveAll(x => ForenameList.Contains(x.Code));

Comment: `newList = originalList.Where(p => stringsList.Contains(p.TheStringPropertyYouLike)`

Comment: try this `List<Person> NewList = AllPeople.Where(x => ForenameList.Contains(x.Code));`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you